# How can i set SQL TAB as reference values for compare with another tab in Node-RED

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have two tab in sql , TAB1 and TAB2. I want to use ;

1. last element TAB2 as reference values.
2. avarage of TAB2 as reference values.
3. max and min element of TAB2 as ref val.

What i did ----

- I can take last element of TAB2,average of TAB 2 and max,min val of TAB2 via function node with JS code.
- I can easily write and read sensor data from sql.

What i need ---

I need compare values  which is belong to TAB2 with TAB1. I cant use switch node for comparing 2 different source. What kind of ways i must follow for achievement this goal ?

Update : For example this is from '' X '' Database , TAB2 Table Last value is 3. ID 5.22322

```
ID      Value
1      0.23123
2      9.33333
3      5.22322
```

This is From '' Y '' Database, TAB1

```
ID      Value
1      1.202123
2      3.3033
3      1.2322
```

Comment: "last element of TAB2" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Oh my bad. It is last measured value in TAB2

Comment: Can you specify more clearly what you mean by _I need compare these 3 items with which is belong to TAB2 with TAB1_ ?   Which _3 items_ ?  What do you mean by _belong to TAB2 with TAB1_ ?  The contents or structure of table TAB1 is also not specified.

Comment: Think about you have Motor1 and Motor2 Database and you want to compare these database and detect which one has hig frequency. For this comparing system what sould i do in node-red to achieve this goal?